# CosmicMind/Material : How to change CheckButton Selected Colour in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, cosmicmind

I am using CheckButton and I am not able to change its selected color for selected state. 
[image: CheckBox with blue color]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution

```
checkBoxButton.setIconColor(Color.darkText.value, for: .selected)
checkBoxButton.setIconColor(Color.darkText.value, for: .normal)
checkBoxButton.checkmarkColor = UIColor.white
checkBoxButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```